# Firestore AngularFire2 5.0 - id's

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Why is it such a rigmarole to get the id for data stored in Firestore vs previous versions where you can directly access the $key? Am I going about this the wrong way in the code below? In the Post model, I have to have a nullable id field of string to store this directly.

```
getCollection$(): Observable<Post[]> {
  return this.afs.collection<Post>()
    .snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
}
```

Also, is there a way to return the id of new documents that are added via the add method?

```
this.afs.collection<Post>(this.path).add(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The author of library `Angularfire2` decided that way :), it looks rigmarole on first time but when you used to it no more problems.

You can define an optional parameter with `?` which will be valid to use in `typescript` check this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters). This will be easy when you only care about the `id`, here you only have one optional parameter.

But when you need more metadata from the `.snapshotChanges()` like `type:'added|removed|modified'`, `fromCache`, `newIndex`, or `oldIndex` extending your current model as described in this official [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#example) will be handy.

```
export interface PostId extends Post { id: string; }

getCollection$(): Observable<PostId[]> {
  return this.afs.collection<Post>()
    .snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
}
```

But here keep in mind that you need to extend the model with id wherever you getting this function.

For your last question

```
//generate an id from firestore
let tempId = this.afs.createId();
this.afs.collection<Post>(this.path).doc(tempId).set(data);
```

Comment: Regarding ID's., I don't want to generate an ID and then set it. I am looking for a way to return the newly generated ID.

Comment: when you generate an id with `.createId()`, that will be same when you do an `add`

Comment: not true - with createId you are explicitly telling firebase what Id to store the document with. if you omit the .doc(tempId) the id that will be autogenerated is different to whats created here

Comment: yes because firestore generate random id each time for `createId()` and `add` you need to do any of one method

Comment: figured it...the id is returned when used like this: this.postsCollection.add(data)
      .then(docRef => docRef.id)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));